# What word can I use as a salutation meaning I am feeling like you are avoiding me

Tags: single-word-requests

Your loving but ___________ Mother!

Comment: How about lonesome?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should add "passive-aggressive" as a coordinate adjective to whatever answer you pick.

Comment: If you want to lay a guilt trip on your adult child, use *devoted*.  But don't!  Instead, focus on keeping the positives in your relationship front and center.  Allow your offspring time to go out into the world without feeling guilty.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to think of ways to say that without *direct* accusation. I came up with

> Your loving but [**neglected**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/neglect) Mother!
>
> Your loving but [**disregarded**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/disregard) Mother!

Answer (score 1):

As in:  *Your loving but forlorn Mother!*

**forlorn**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/forlorn)

> - a. Abandoned, deserted, or desolate
> - b. Sad or lonely, especially from being deserted or abandoned
> - c. Suggesting or characterized by sadness or loneliness

The ultimate pity potty ... use the adjective forlorn to express loneliness and feeling left out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use "[estranged](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/estranged?s=t)" to evoke a sense of being made a stranger.